# Whats the need to put the Tomcat's context.xml inside META-INF of Web App

Tags: servlets, tomcat6

I have a basic question,there are two incidents happended while working with Tomcat.

1.I want to share the context between two web applications deployed under same Tomcat container, all I want to do is make *crossContext=true* in *context.xml* initally, I did that in *{CATALINAHOME}/conf/context.xml* didnt worked out. Later I got the solution from our own Stack Overflow then I put the context.xml inside META-INF, everything worked as expected.

2.Similarly when I configure the *Data Source* for my Web App,I did the same initally then I put the context.xml with required JDBC configurations inside META-INF then it got worked.

So my question is why Tomcat is picking the context.xml configuration's from META-INF? What I'm missing while configuring in {CATALINAHOME}/conf's context.xml ?  What I need to understand ?

Need your knowledge and the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you're working with Tomcat from inside an IDE like Eclipse. This way Tomcat's own `/context.xml` will indeed be ignored. The IDE uses just sole the server engine and creates a separate deploy and work space in the IDE environment. In Eclipse, you can find a copy of the `/context.xml` in the *Servers* project. This one is editable and will be applied. But providing another one in webapp's `/META-INF` is of course also a solution and it's more portable.

Tomcat's own `/context.xml` is only used when you start it standalone by `startup.bat/sh` and so on, outside the IDE environment.

Comment: Thanks Balus.,I have tried running the Tomcat outside IDE and it picked the context.xml and worked as expected. I also seen the deployed WAR inside Workspace plugins when I do through IDE. Now one question came into mind for curiosity,why IDE is creating separate deploy folder, is there any specific reason?

Comment: So that it does not disturb the "externally configured" setup. All the IDE needs is the sole server engine. In case of Eclipse, you can however configure the IDE to take over Tomcat entirely. This way its default homepage will also be visible when you run from inside the IDE.

Comment: Thanks a lot Balus, for your knowledge sharing